# Delay in CUPS socket backend

Tags: cups

Using the raw driver to send pre-generated PCL directly to the printer, I get response times around 4 s. When I send it to the printer using `netcat` I get about 300 ms.

It seems that there is some problem with CUPS' socket backend: http://pastebin.com/NmDGss1A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CUPS forum](http://www.cups.org/newsgroups.php?s0%20gcups.general%20T0) this is a bug in CUPS 1.4.3 which causes an SNMP request for supply levels even for raw queues (for normal queues you can disable it in the PPD file):

> OK, this is a known bug in the 1.4.3 socket backend; the 1.4.7 and
>   later releases disable SNMP supply level lookups (the source of the
>   delay) for raw queues.